# Sails.js - API attribute not changing via PUT

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am following a tutorial written for node/express and attempting to adapt it to sails. I am using Postman to Put name : Chris @ localhost:1337/api/data/5591bbdedabb79240b34a46b

```
sails -v
0.11.0

node -v
0.12.4
```

Here is my controller:

```
  modify_one: function (req, res) {

    Api.findById(req.params.data_id, function(err, data, callback) {

    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    data.name = req.body.name;

    data.update({data_id:req.params.data_id},{$set: {name:req.body.name}}, callback)

    })
```

Route:

```
'PUT /api/data/:data_id': 'ApiController.modify_one',
```

If I GET /api/data it doesn't show the modification. howver the res.json(data.name) returns the correct change.

Any thoughts? It must be something with it not saving in the mongodb?

Comment: I changed the question around a little and there is no error. You caught it before saving the changes.

Comment: I don't see where you're saving your change to the database. You're getting the current document, changing it locally, then returning it, never saving.

Comment: If you're using mongoose, all you would need to add is data.save(function () {/*res.json(...) goes here*/})

Comment: When I try to add `data.save(function(err) { if (err) res.send(err);` I get the TYpe: Undefined error.

Comment: Right, since you're using the mongodb driver, you'll need to use it's api. I don't think it comes with .save.

Comment: Ahhhh... n00b. Look slike it might be .update instead of .save

Comment: .update(query,actionToTake,options,callback). so, `.update({_id:theid},{$set: {fieldA:valueA}},callback)`

Comment: installing mongoose instead :/

Comment: Not a bad idea. :) be sure to enable debug mode in development though, it'll give you a lot of insight to what it does behind the scenes.

Comment: I am using `data.update({data_id:req.params.data_id},{$set: {name:req.body.name}}, callback)` and getting "callback is not defined".

Comment: well. you were supposed to put a callback there, not use a non-existent variable that i made up. :)

Comment: I've never used monodb ... very new to sails too. Shoot, I am new to JavaScript as well rofl. Struggling.

Comment: A callback is just another name for a function that is passed to another function that is expected to be called when the function is complete.

Comment: I updated the OP with my best attempt... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using mongoose now?

Comment: negative... got lost with that initiative...I think I was trying to over complicate it.